# Ending with an n or m on adjectives?

Tags: adjective-ending

Is it called

> Auf dem transformierte**n** Bild

or

> Auf dem transformierte**m** Bild

and whats the rule for this?

Edit:
All found answers are not covering dative.

Comment: The question is about the same grammatical phenomenon (weak vs strong declension of adjectives), but the dative isn't covered.

Comment: The adjective ending on `n` is correct here. Loosely spoken, there is already an `m` in `dem`, so you don't need another. So it is `auf dem transformierten Bild`, or `auf einem transformierten Bild`, but `auf transformiertem Bild`. I don't know the exact grammatical rule, but the `only one m` "rule" has always worked for me. <g>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is one m and one n, basically. If the article ends with an m, the subject will end with an n. That's how I learnt it, at least. Just so know, most native speakers will not know / do this wrong. ;)

Comment: Auf dem transformierten, roten, scharfen, kleinen Bild - one m, multiple n.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a definite article, the weak declension is used for the adjective, so **transformierten** (dative) is correct.

Since it's *das Bild*, the gender is neuter. Here's the forms for all cases:

```
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
|Case|Singular             |Plural              |
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
|Nom |das transformierte   |die transformierten |
|Gen |des transformierten  |der transformierten |
|Dat |dem transformierten  |den transformierten |
|Akk |das transformierte   |die transformierten |
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Without an article, the strong declension is used:

```
+----+-----------------+----------------+
|Case|Singular         |Plural          |
+----+-----------------+----------------+
|Nom |transformiertes  |transformierte  |
|Gen |transformierten  |transformierter |
|Dat |transformiertem  |transformierten |
|Akk |transformiertes  |transformierte  |
+----+-----------------+----------------+
```

So if the "dem" were missing, *transformiertem* would be correct.